# Android Development - Playing card flip animation

Tags: android

I was wondering what is the best way of going about implementing a playing card flip animation. I am implementing this to include it in a simple planning poker application. In more detail, In the main screen there will be several cards to choose from with unique numbers(hours) on them. Once clicked it will be animated to face down position ( hidden). Once clicked again the card will be animated to face up position and reveal the number on the card. Thank you for your time.

Regards,

Ryan

Comment: What version of Android are you targeting? What have you tried?

Comment: Hi Larry, I am using the latest version so 18 or 19? I am fairly new to android development so I am looking for a starting point.

Answer (score 2):

I try not to post answers with just links but if your targeting the latest versions of Android you should be able to find lots of info with a simple Google search. Start at the Android developer website and post a new question if you have trouble.

http://developer.android.com/training/animation/cardflip.html